# Generating Golfer Statistics in Python List

Tags: python, django

```
class Score(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(User)
    hole = models.ForeignKey(Hole)
    strokes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Hole(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    par = models.IntegerField()

for score in Score.objects.filter(player=request.user):
    if score.strokes - score.hole.par == 0:
        statistics['pars'] +=1
    elif score.strokes - score.hole.par == 1:
        statistics['bogies'] +=1
    elif score.strokes - score.hole.par == 2:
        statistics['doubles'] +=1
    elif score.strokes - score.hole.par >= 3:
        statistics['triples'] +=1
    elif score.strokes - score.hole.par == -1:
        statistics['birdies'] +=1
    elif score.strokes - score.hole.par <= -2:
        statistics['eagles'] +=1
```

I have the models and code above that is used to determine how many pars/birdies/bogies etc. a golfer has for each Score. This works fine for each individual user's statistics.

I'm also able to pull all of the scores and group them

```
Score.objects.values('player', 'strokes')
```

but what would be the best approach for pulling every score, grouping scores by player, then generating statistics for each player that can be used in a template?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck.  You outlined the approach; it seems that you need a tutorial on manipulating data frames, rather than specific help from Stack Overflow.  Do you have a coding attempt to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...Well you COULD look at the data after it's been entered into the database, Or you could make a new field in the "Scores" model called "stroke_type" or something (sorry not a golf guy, don't know the term). Before submitting data into the DB (before save() in your views), do the math in python and generate the data for "stroke_type" yourself, for every submission of a "Scores" object. This column would be populated with the strings "Birdy, Bogey, Eagle, etc." which with the power of SQL will make it much easier to generate these "statistics."

Comment: This approach ended up being much more efficient. Thank you